# Which regression algorithm could be applied for correcting sensor values?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, arima

Please consider the sample dataset below.

In simple terms, 
Sensor is defective and hence measured incorrect values since 2000 and we have the data for 10 years with both: measured and actual.

P.S. Although we dont have data for each combination of the application and sensor type on monthly basis.

Now, we want to have the actual from the algorithm for actual values.

We tried, XGBoost and CatBoost by creating another column named diff = measured- actual
and fed to the algorithm to identify the pattern. but not sure which algorithm is appropriate although suspecting **Neural network or Time series (ARIMA)** could work but not sure
because we have just 10 years data on monthly level

```
library(tidyverse)

train_data <- data.frame(
  time = c(rep("01.2000",10),rep("02.2000",10),rep(".",3),rep("11.2010",10),rep("12.2010",10)),
  application = c(rep("factory",4),rep("residential",3),rep("research",3),
                  rep("factory",2),rep("residential",5),rep("research",3),
                  rep(".",3),
                  rep("factory",2),rep("residential",2),rep("research",6),
                  rep("factory",7),rep("residential",1),rep("research",2)),
  sensor = c(LETTERS[1:10],LETTERS[10:1],rep(".",3),LETTERS[c(5:1,10:6)],LETTERS[c(3:9,2,1,10)]), 
  measured = c(26.4,2000,1001,23.9,100000,0,1234,12098,34567,0,
               123,676,12,0,100,0,0,98,1,190,
               rep(".",3),
               3454,0,101,9,1,0,14,1298,677,0,
               264,20220,1851,3.9,1044,0,1764,0,34,0),
  actual =  c(26.4,2010,1001,23.9,100100,237,1234,12098,34567,19583,
              123,706,1112,156,100,650,109,98,10,190,
              rep(".",3),
              3454,10,101,19,10,40,44,1298,760,50,
              264,20220,1851,39,1048,870,1765,40,35,1110)
)

# to forecast actual 
test_data <- data.frame(
  time = rep("01.2011",10),
  application = c(rep("factory",7),rep("residential",1),rep("research",2)),
  sensor = LETTERS[c(1,4,5,9,3,2,8,6,7,10)], 
  measured = c(26.4,100000,0,0,
               123,12,
               3454,0,20220,1851)
)

How can we predict/forecast the actual values for 01.2011 data (test_data) ?
```

Comment: What kind of sensor?  What went wrong: calibration driff? user error?  This could be important since it dictates how your target value presents.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `xgboost` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with the appropriate language tag `r`).

Comment: @grldsndrs, it is calibration error and as the sensor decays over time we got to consider the time variant.

Comment: @desertnaut, the reason to add XGBoost, it that, we had tried it but couldnt as mentioned.

Comment: Can you say what kind of sensor?  What are you measuring: temp, load ...?  Are you sampling current or voltage, or is there some processing going on before the sample  is recorded?

Comment: @grldsndrs, Actually, due to data privacy, using the term sensor, actually, it is nothing to do with sensor but just measurement. please consider data without any prejudice about the background such has something to do with volume/temperature/air etc